# rounding a number (floor) in r

Tags: r, rounding, floor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

I was trying to round a number. The following are fine:

```
floor(3)
[1] 3
```

however:

```
floor (0.6 / 0.2)
[1] 2
```

or

```
 x <- 0.6 / 0.2
 floor (x) 
[1] 2
```

Why not 3 ?

Edit:

I am not concern with mechanics rather I want it be consistently rounded to 3, so that my function work properly.

Edit2:

I was not thinking something complex (as in the following discussion and not trying to prove as if to prove R is not doing its work), with help of suggestion below particularly from Matthew Lundberg, I could figure out a way through, may be some like me find useful. So this is what I did -

```
x1 <- 0.6 *100
x2 <- 0.2 *100
floor (x1/x2)
[1] 3
```

Comment: My question was not why ? rather how I can make it work see my edit

Comment: As written, you can't make it work without breaking other cases.  Determine why you need a ratio of inexact values, and change that.

Comment: This is not an R question. The priciples apply to any language where there is a trunc or floor function, i.e. pretty much any computer language. If you are having trouble with (extremely basic) concepts in numerical analysis, then ... do your homework.

Comment: thank you all for the comments, as DWin said I might need some homework ...